# PHP contact form - attachment limit problem, additional field, reset form after sending

Tags: php, jquery, contact-form

I'm using "jQuery Contact Form with Attachment using PHP" from PHPPOT website but I need your help with mentioned problems I have.

First, I would like to increase attachment limit which is now 2 MB. I asked my ISP to set new parameters in php.ini but they've said that my limit is already 32 MB. Unfortunately, when I try to send the file bigger than 2 MB I've got message "Could not access file:" and receive the mail without attachment.

Second thing, I would like to add additional filed "Telephone number" to my contact form and I've done everything I have conclude logically (just to remark that I'm PHP noob :( ) but I cannot make this info to be part of my e-mail.

And the last thing...how can I force the form to be reset after successful sending?

Thanks a lot!!!

Below are the PHP files and you can se my form here: https://test.arhviz.rs/Test.html

**index.php**

```
    <style>
body{width:100%;}
#frmContact {border-top:#F0F0F0 0px solid;background:rgba(250,248,248,0.00);padding:10px;}
#frmContact div{margin-bottom: 15px}
#frmContact div label{margin-left: 5px}
.demoInputBox{padding:10px; border:#27aae1 0px solid; border-radius:4px;background-color:#C6C6C6;width:100%;}
.error{background-color: #FF5A5A;border:#AA4502 0px solid;padding: 5px 10px;color: #FFFFFF;border-radius:4px;}
.success{background-color: #27AAE1;border:#0FA015 0px solid;padding: 5px 10px;color: #FFFFFF;border-radius:4px;}
.info{font-size:.8em;color: #FF5A5A;letter-spacing:2px;padding-left:5px;}
.btnAction{background-color:#27AAE1;border:0;padding:10px 40px;color:#FFF;border:#F0F0F0 0px solid; border-radius:4px;}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e){
$("#frmContact").on('submit',(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loader-icon').show();
    var valid;  
    valid = validateContact();
    if(valid) {
        $.ajax({
        url: "contact_mail.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data){
        $("#mail-status").html(data);
        $('#loader-icon').hide();
        },
        error: function(){}             
        
        });
    }
}));

function validateContact() {
    var valid = true;   
    $(".demoInputBox").css('background-color','');
    $(".info").html('');
    
    if(!$("#userName").val()) {
        $("#userName-info").html("(required)");
        $("#userName").css('background-color','#FF5A5A');
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!$("#userEmail").val()) {
        $("#userEmail-info").html("(required)");
        $("#userEmail").css('background-color','#FF5A5A');
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!$("#userEmail").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
        $("#userEmail-info").html("(invalid)");
        $("#userEmail").css('background-color','#FF5A5A');
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!$("#userPhone").val().match(/[0-9]/)) {
        $("#userPhone-info").html("(invalid)");
        $("#userPhone").css('background-color','#FF5A5A');
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!$("#subject").val()) {
        $("#subject-info").html("(required)");
        $("#subject").css('background-color','#FF5A5A');
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!$("#content").val()) {
        $("#content-info").html("(required)");
        $("#content").css('background-color','#FF5A5A');
        valid = false;
    }
    
    return valid;
}

});
</script>
<form id="frmContact" action="" method="post">
<div id="mail-status"></div>
<div>
<label style="padding-top:20px;">Ime</label>
<span id="userName-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
<label>E-mail</label>
<span id="userEmail-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
<label>Telefon</label>
<span id="userPhone-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="text" name="userPhone" id="userPhone" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
<label>Pošaljite Vaš projekat (DWG, DXF ili PDF):</label><br/>
<input type="file" name="attachmentFile" id="attachmentFile" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
<label>Tema</label> 
<span id="subject-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
<label>Poruka</label> 
<span id="content-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<textarea name="content" id="content" class="demoInputBox" cols="60" rows="6"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="btnAction" />
</div>
</form>
<div id="loader-icon" style="display:none;"><img src="LoaderIcon.gif" /></div>
```

**contact_mail.php**

```
    <?php
require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port     = 465;  
$mail->Username = "kontakt@arhviz.rs";
$mail->Password = "*****";
$mail->Host     = "mail.arhviz.rs";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddAddress("igor.kulundzic@gmail.com");  
$mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
$mail->WordWrap   = 80;
$mail->MsgHTML($_POST["content"]);

if(is_array($_FILES)) {
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']); 
}

$mail->IsHTML(true);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "<p class='error'>Došlo je do greške pri slanju poruke. Molim, pokušajte kasnije ili pošaljite mail direktno na igor.kulundzic@gmail.com. Hvala!.</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p class='success'>Poruka je uspešno poslata. Potrudiću se da Vam odgovorima u najkraćem roku. Hvala.</p>";
}   
?>
```

There are also three files in folder phpmailer but I think they are just configuration files for connection with server.

Comment: Please restrict your question to one issue at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that in these two lines...

```
$mail->MsgHTML($_POST["userPhone"]);
$mail->MsgHTML($_POST["content"]);
```

...you first set the phone number as mail content and then override it with the actual message. Try it like this:

```
$mail->MsgHTML( 'Phone: ' . $_POST["userPhone"] . "\nMessage: " . $_POST["content"] );
```

As for resetting the form: You seem to be sending the E-Mail via an AJAX request. There is already a function in your index.php code that runs after the successfull sending of the E-Mail:

```
success: function(data){
    $("#mail-status").html(data);
    $('#loader-icon').hide();
}
```

That's the point where you could reset the form, e.g. like this:

```
success: function(data){
    $("#mail-status").html(data);
    $('#loader-icon').hide();
    $('#frmContact').trigger("reset");
}
```

**Update:** I tried to make it clearer, where the reset call needs to go. If it's part of the success function, it should only happen, if sending the mail was successful.

**Update 2:** A first step should be to check that the values of the file limitations are what you think they are. You can output the values like these:

```
<?php
echo "<!-- upload_max_filesize=" . ini_get('upload_max_filesize') . ", post_max_size=" . ini_get('post_max_size') . "-->";
```

Put that at the end of the index.php file, after the loader icon. Then refresh the website and have a look at the source code of the page. Once the values are what you expect them to be, remove it again.

Comment: Hey Johannes,

thanks for your answer...I have manage to set Phone number to be included in mail body! But I'm not sure how to set the reset function...when I put this raw after the part of script you have mentioned, the form just reset without sending. It should reset after sending and after showing the message that it has been sent successfully. :(

Also, you haven't give me the instructions how to increase the limit of attachment above 2MB...

Comment: ...or if it's not possible to set function delay, it will be useful to have Reset button...to activate reset function?

Comment: Hey, I have just find the solution for reset the form...with delay ;)

Now, there's only one problem left...attachment larger than 2 MB :(

Any solution?

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to find out what the actual limitations are.

Comment: Hm...looks like something missing in this code you have send me....I have put it at the end of index.php after loader icon raw, as you've said...but I didn't get any feedback info in page source... :(

Comment: You can check too: https://test.arhviz.rs/Test.html

Comment: HEY, I did it!!! I have found on my cPanel that the php.ini file was set to 2MB limit...obviously, guys from ISP don't know where to look for this info...now, everything works fine!!!

Thanks a lot!!!!